# Text keeps moving over navigation

Tags: html, css

My vertical navbar is having text go over it when the browser window is resized. I have set up columns, so I'm unsure why text from another column is overlapping it. So does anyone know what is going on, I have tried 'positon: fixed' with no luck. This is a very basic site, but any help is appreaciated, thanks.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
.username {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14pt;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.vertical-nav {
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.vertical-nav a {
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.contact-email {}

.contact-email p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.about-me {}

.about-me p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 10pt;
  width: 300px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
}

.left {
  width: 10%;
}

.right {
  width: 75%;
}

.row {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ren</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column left">
      <header>
        <h1>
          <span class="username">Ren</span>
        </h1>
      </header>

      <div class="vertical-nav">
        <a href="#">Work/Concepts</a>
        <a href="#">Instagram</a>
        <a href="#">Soundcloud</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column right">
      <div class="contact-email">
        <p>
          email: placeholderhere@gmail.com
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="about-me">
        <p>
          Creative amature from Australia. Planning on studying audio engineering soon. Currently concept clothing designer.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Give us your code to help you.

Comment: @ashfaq.p I did, just was changing it.

Comment: @Pete Thanks, didn't see that, must of forgot to change it.l

Comment: I think your problem is that you are given your elements defined widths and the content is larger than the width you define.  You either need to change the widths to be min-widths or be larger on smaller screens (use media queries) or just be larger on every screen

Comment: Ok thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You specified the vertical-nav to be 200px wide but the .left container only has 10% which is less so it leaks over. So you will have to decide what to do - give more than 10% and think about what to do if there is not enough space like the text-overflow ellipsis in this snippet OR make the links inline elements with a word break.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
.username {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14pt;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.vertical-nav {
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.vertical-nav a {
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 10pt;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.contact-email {}

.contact-email p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.about-me {}

.about-me p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 10pt;
  width: 300px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
}

.left {
  width: 10%;
}

.right {
  width: 75%;
}

.row {}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column left">

    <header>
      <h1>
        <span class="username">Ren</span>
      </h1>
    </header>


    <div class="vertical-nav">
      <a href="#">Work/Concepts</a>
      <a href="#">Instagram</a>
      <a href="#">Soundcloud</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column right">
    <div class="contact-email">
      <p>
        email: placeholderhere@gmail.com
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="about-me">
      <p>
        Creative amature from Australia. Planning on studying audio engineering soon. Currently concept clothing designer.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: or simply use a more elegant way like flexbox or inline-block and avoir ALL these code and % and overflow, etc etc

Comment: Of course there are plenty more possibilites, just the two that came quickly to my mind and require minimal changes to the post's code

Comment: Still overlaps, I think I will restart my code. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I defined a `flexbox` for the row and took the liberty to clean up your CSS a bit.
I changed the width of the vertical-nav from 10% to 20%. You can change that back if desired.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.username {
  font-size: 14pt;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.vertical-nav {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.vertical-nav a {
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.about-me p {
  width: 300px;
}

.left {
  width: 20%;
}

.left h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.right {
  flex: 1 0; /* Grow to use all the space left */
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column left">
    <header>
      <h1>
        <span class="username">Ren</span>
      </h1>
    </header>
    <div class="vertical-nav">
      <a href="#">Work/Concepts</a>
      <a href="#">Instagram</a>
      <a href="#">Soundcloud</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column right">
    <div class="contact-email">
      <p>
        email: placeholderhere@gmail.com
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="about-me">
      <p>
        Creative amature from Australia. Planning on studying audio engineering soon. Currently concept clothing designer.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```